# Create PDF with Images in ReportLab inside AWS-Lambda with Python

Tags: python, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, reportlab

I successfully wrote a python-script, which create the PDF I want. Inside the PDF are several images. 
In my local environment everything works fine, when ReportLab grab the images from my desktop. 
Now I want to transfer the script to AWS-Lambda and it is driving me crazy.
ReportLab and Pillow are Layers for AWS-Lambda. Newest versions installed with pip3.
I download my images from S3 and save it to the localSpace from Lambda like so:

```
local_name = '/tmp/'
logoImage = local_name+'logo.png'

def downloadLogo():
    logoPath = 'QRData/logo.png'
    try:
       s3.Bucket(bucketName).download_file(logoPath, logoImage)
    except ClientError as e:
       print(e)
       if e.response['Error']['Code'] == "404":
           print("The object does not exist.")
       else:
           raise
       return False
    return True
```

After downloading successfully the image,ReportLab throws me an error, when I want to draw the image from the localSpace.

```
def setLogo(c):
    c.drawImage(logoImage, x, y, width=400/4, height=171/4)
```

ErrorMessage:

```
JPEG Unsupported JPEG marker: ce
Imaging Library not available, unable to import bitmaps only jpegs
fileName=<_io.BufferedReader name='/tmp/logo.png'> identity=[ImageReader@0x7f0a0dd34280 filename='/tmp/logo.png']
fileName=<_io.BufferedReader name='/tmp/logo.png'> identity=[ImageReader@0x7f0a0dd34280 filename='/tmp/logo.png']
```

Why can ReportLab grab my image locally, but not in Lambda and how can I solve this error?

Comment: Are the downloader form S3 and the reportLab generator, part of the same process Lambda? Take into account that the /tmp dir in Lambda function will survive just for the time the lambda is running....

Comment: Yes same process. I figured out, that modules deployed on windows/Mac and loaded to Lambda layers don't work properly. Will dig deeper into it soon.

Comment: @Chris any update in 2020 ? facing the same issue

Comment: As a workaround til today I used an external layer from here : https://github.com/keithrozario/Klayers

Comment: @Chris can you please share your serverless.yaml configuration for this service? I could able to create the layer but its still not working as expected.